# Prime avoidance lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$  be a commutative ring. $A$ is an ideal of $R$, and $P_1,P_2,...,P_s$ are prime ideals of $R$ such that $$A \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{s} P_j.$$ 
Prove that there exists some $P_j$ such that $A\subseteq P_j$.

Comment: see any standard book. like atiyah. read the chapter.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry for not giving my thoughts. I just wanted some hints of this problem originally. And it's not for homework but only curiosity as I encountered it in a book which had no interpretation to help me solve it. Next time I'll try more with myself and tell them out before asking help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideas & hints:

Induction on $\;s\;$: for $\;s=1\;$ it is trivial (for $\;s=2\;$ we don't even need the ideals in the union to be prime! Yet for more than two we do need primality).

Assume for any union of prime ideals up to $\;s-1\;,\;\;s>2\;$ . Now, if $\;A\;$ is already contained in the union of *less* than $\;s\;$ of those prime ideals the inductive hypothesis kicks in and we're done, so we can go now by reductio ad absurdum and assume the claim is false:

$$\exists\,a_1,a_2,...,a_s\in A\;\;\text{s.t.}\;\;a_i\in P_i\;,\;\;a_i\notin\bigcup_{k=1,\,k\neq i}^s P_k\;,\;\;\forall\;i=1,2,...,s$$

and let us take now for all $\;i\;$ :

$$x_i:=\prod_{k=1,\,k\neq i}^s a_k\implies x_i\notin P_i\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

Reach now a contradiction by considering where does the following element lie

$$r:=\sum_{i=1}^sx_i.$$

Comment: Do you think this could be showed directly? Without using contracdition?

Comment: Perhaps @AaronMaroja, yet for me the above is pretty straightforward and works fine.

Comment: No disagreeing on that, absolutely.

Comment: It's better this way. I tried without contradiction.